# Work with bindings in angular components

Tags: html, angularjs, binding, components

Hi I've I use some different angular components in my code. One of this is a input helper for some number fields in my web application.

Important: Please read this description step by step to understand, because it's really hard to describe this problem, I gave my best to do this. :)

I have a component which has the tag `<input-helper></input-helper>`, which loads the template of the component. This I can put around a random input in my html and it adds a div in form of an button on the right side of my input. I also have a binding in my component, to pass throught the value from the input (if there is some) or to update the value, when it's clear and I type something with the component. So it looks like this:

```
<input-helper-addon current-value="inputValue">
    <input type="number" ng-model="inputValue">
</input-helper-addon>
```

In the controller of my input helper component I have follow binding, where I catch the value of the input above, that is transcluded:

```
static componentOptions = {
    transclude: true,
    bindings: {
        currentValue: "="
    }
}
```

In the template of my input helper component I have something like this:

```
<div class="inputHelperAddonComp">
    <!--HERE IS THE TRANSCLUDED INPUT-->
    <div ng-transclude></div>
    <!--HERE IS THE BUTTON WHICH IS ON THE RIGHT OF THE INPUT-->
    <div class="inputAddonRight" tooltip="{template='<input-helper></input-helper>'}">
        <img src="./randomIcon.svg">
    </div>
    <!--HERE I PRINT THE VALUE FROM THE INPUT - IT WORKS-->
    {{ currentValue }}
</div>
```

Now I get the correct value from the input and with the binding `currentValue: "="` I can watch it and update in on both sides (in the input and in the component).

Now look at follow line in the template of my `input-helper-addon` component:

```
<div class="inputAddonRight" tooltip="{template='<input-helper></input-helper>'}">
```

There you can see, that I have another binding `tooltip`, which is a plugin to handle a tooltip. There I can give to the tooltip another template, which has to be displayed in the tooltip. You can see, there is inline-html possible, so I give directly the tag of another component `input-helper` within.

The second component `input-helper`, which shows the input-helper keys, has also a template and an own directive like the `input-helper-addon` component. They look like this:

I used again a binding called currentValue in the directive:

```
static componentOptions = {
    bindings: {
        currentValue: "="
    }
}
```

So now, the input-helper component also needs the value of the input and I have to pass it once again.

When we go back to the input-helper-addon, I thought, I can give the binding again in the template of the tooltip, with the value of the currentValue binding of the directive from the input-helper-addon like this:

```
<div class="inputAddonRight" tooltip="{template='<input-helper current-value=&quot;currentValue&quot;></input-helper>'}">
```

When I try to display the value in the template of the input-helper component I got nothing:

```
<div class="inputHelperComp">
{{ currentValue }}
</div>
```

Here a picture that perhaps helps to understand:

[image]

I pass in the component tag of input-helper-addon the value of the input in my html in the first binding, get it correct and can display it and change it in both sides because of the `'='` in my binding definition. After that I have in the template of the input-helper-addon another component tag with the same binding, so I tried to pass it throught again with the value from the directive, but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Sorry for this complicate question, but I had no other ideas...

Thanks and cheers.

Comment: try: current-value="$ctrl.currentValue">

Comment: Can you please provide plunker or jsfiddle?

Comment: Hi @varit05 I would like, but it's impossible the web application is so big and complicate and the components work with a lot of superclasses and other logic, that it wouldn't be possible to show the exactly effect...Sorry. I only can try to make a smaller example of the same idea...

Comment: @gyc Hi - don't work :(